# Scala generics - simplify number of generic arguments

Tags: scala, generics

I have this class defined as follows:

```
abstract class MyHelper[T, E <: BaseHelper[T]](implicit clsTag: ClassTag[E]) {

  val all: Array[E]

  def parse(t: T): Try[E] = { ... }
}
```

and this is how I am using it:

```
trait IntHelper extends BaseHelper[Int] {}

object MyIntHelper extends MyHelper[Int, IntHelper] { }
```

How do I simplify `MyHelper` class definition to accept only the inner generic type T instead of passing two types, E and T?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for you to directly enforce `T` in `MyHelper` since you're only using `E` itself.

So something like this should be fine.

```scala
abstract class MyHelper[E <: BaseHelper[_]](implicit clsTag: ClassTag[E]) {
  val all: Array[E]
}
```

A more fleshed out example looks like:

```scala
trait BaseHelper[T] {}
trait IntHelper extends BaseHelper[Int]

abstract class MyHelper[E <: BaseHelper[_]](implicit clsTag: ClassTag[E]) {
  val all: Array[E]
}

object MyIntHelper extends MyHelper[IntHelper] { 
  override val all = Array(new IntHelper{}, new IntHelper{}) 
}

// just to ensure it works
MyIntHelper.all
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and it didn't work, it's because I'm using `T` in `MyHelper`. I've modified the sample code to include a `parse` function to illustrate this use case.

Comment: If you need to use both T and E as types I don't see an obvious way around declaring both.  I was wondering if you could use implicits in the pattern so that the BaseHelper doesn't have to be specified directly, but then needing its type would still get you.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more.  Good luck.